# Can't find the launch icons for Visual Studio 2010 ultimate anywhere?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I seem to have a really unique problem with my visual studio 2010 installation. Before installing visual studio i installed SQL Server 2012 express and SQL Server Management Studio. After that i installed Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. The installation goes fine but after it is complete i can't find the application launch icons anywhere. the only new programs that are added are Microsoft Test Manager and Microsoft Visual Studio Documentation. Please Help me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the Service pack 1 for it to work! You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23691)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which OS you are running but I'm using Windows 8, and I'm dealing with the same issue. I was able to start VS2010 by clicking on the SQL Server Data Tool icon (same as the VS2010 icon). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not even in the directory under program files(x86)? 
You could try to open the installation again, if it detects Visual Studio it will ask you to repair the installation :)

Answer (score 0):

I right clicked on the .csproj file > open with >...

Comment: Or search for SQL Server Data Tools

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Visual Studio program is Service Pack 1; that is why it can't work with sqlserver express edition. I faced same issue but fixed it by installing sqlserver 2008 Service Pack 2 in place of sql server Express I was previously using.